# What do these different types of pin shapes mean?

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, schematics, pins, pinout

[image]

Do these pins with different shapes have special meaning. Is there an industry standard for pin shapes and sizes?
I have also noticed that some solder pads on boards are of Square shape and most of them are in round shape, Is there a special meaning for this too?

Answer (score 3):

The label arrow shapes may be used to give meaning for signal direction. A label pointing to one direction describes from where the signal comes out and to where it goes in. A double arrow shape would mean a bi-directional signal. But by looking at the shapes and signal names, most of the signals are likely labeled as bi-directional even though they might be unidirectional.

Solder pads of different shapes may also have a meaning. A square is typically pin 1 and other pins are round.

But it is difficult to guess if these apply to your board or not. These are not standards, and not required. These are just good practice if you want to make an easily readable and understandable schematic and PCB.

Answer (score 3):

The schematic symbols shown can be used to differentiate between bidirectional, input and output port labels. For example (from [here](https://altiumpcbdesigner.blogspot.com/2012/11/sheet-to-sheet-references.html)):

[image]

The top three are outputs in the above diagram.

Solder pads shapes are determined by function typically, but sometimes a different shape is used to indicate pin 1 of a package (from [here](https://forum.kicad.info/t/mbi5026gn-and-mbi5026gf-footprints/20458/8)).

[image]